# remove an Alert Controller if another Alert Controller is called to be shown

Tags: ios, swift, alert, uialertcontroller

My app needs to show some info to the user at different times.
I decided to use AlertControllers but I cannot display two Alert Controllers at the same time.
Thus I need to know if an Alert Controller is shown, close it and open another one.

I've done this so far. I'm using `self.presentedViewController` to check is the AlertController is shown or not. But I cannot figure out how to close it.
I tried with

```
self.presentedViewController?.removeFromParentViewController()
```

and

```
self.presentedViewController?.delete(self.presentedViewController)
```

with no luck. Someone can help me? Thanks

Comment: both the alertController presented by same ViewController class?

Comment: @SumitGarg Yes! But I'm open to new implementations

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just call `dismissViewControllerAnimated` on the presented `AlertController`. You can present the next one in the `completion` block if you want.

```
self.alertViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {

 })
```

Comment: amazing I just wrote: if self.presentedViewController != nil { self.presentedViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) }